# How to get unique records with join tables and without using group by

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to get unique record from 2 tables without using `Group By` instead of i want to use `DISTINCT` because when i used `group by` it does not return last updated records.

I used following query with Group By.

```
SELECT  au.id, o.order_id,o.payment_method, o.order_date,au.article_id FROM `orders` as o INNER JOIN austpost_api_response as au ON  o.order_id = au.order_id  where o.shipment_status = 1 AND au.active_status = 1 AND o.order_status = 0 group by o.order_id
ORDER BY `au`.`id`  DESC
```

It's returns unique order_id but not getting last updated order_id

For example...

`Order number` 1212 has four `article_id` id 45,76,47,48 but once i used this with `group by` it's display unique order id but not getting 48 last updated record instead of it's return 45.

is it possible to get with `DISTINCT`  keyword.

Comment: what is your mysql version

Comment: phpmyadmin 4.8.3

Answer (score 1):

You can use row_number() function if your mysql version 8.0+

```
select * from
(
SELECT  au.id, o.order_id,o.payment_method, o.order_date,au.article_id,row_number() over(partition by o.order_id order by o.order_date desc) as rn
FROM `orders` as o INNER JOIN austpost_api_response as au ON  o.order_id = au.order_id  where o.shipment_status = 1 AND au.active_status = 1 AND o.order_status = 0 
)A where rn=1
```

OR You can try using correlated subquery

```
SELECT  au.id, o.order_id,o.payment_method, o.order_date,au.article_id
FROM `orders` as o INNER JOIN austpost_api_response as au ON  o.order_id = au.order_id  
where o.shipment_status = 1 AND au.active_status = 1 AND o.order_status = 0 and o.order_date in 
(
  select max(o.order_date) from `orders` o1 where o.order_id = o1.order_id and o1.order_status = 0
)
```

Comment: @SamirSheikh, updated my answer - you can try 2nd solution

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have multiple rows for the responses for each order -- and you want the most recent one per order.

You want to *filter* the data, not aggregate it.  I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT au.id, o.order_id, o.payment_method, o.order_date, au.article_id
FROM orders o INNER JOIN
     austpost_api_response au
     ON o.order_id = au.order_id  
WHERE o.shipment_status = 1 AND
      au.active_status = 1 AND
      o.order_status = 0 AND
      au.id = (SELECT MAX(au2.id)
               FROM austpost_api_response au2
               WHERE au2.order_id = au.order_id AND
                     au2.active_status = 1
              )
ORDER BY au.id DESC;
```